# How to show half of near pages stacked beneath the current page in PageView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a way to implement this using PageView, any other package or even manually?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same result using this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper. You can customize the position of the cards to get the design you want

You can use the customLayoutOption to modify the position and can get the desired position.

```
customLayoutOption: CustomLayoutOption(
                      startIndex: 1,
                      stateCount: 4,
                    ).addTranslate([
                      Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                      Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                      Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                      Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                    ]).addScale([1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4], Alignment.bottomLeft),
```

Comment: How to customize the position?

Comment: You can customize it with the customLayoutOption. I have updated with a example you will need to position where you want the cards to get the result you want.

Comment: I have updated my answer so you can know how to customise the cards position.

Comment: Thank you, but nothing changed when I added this even if I try different values

Comment: You need to change the OffSet values to your desire to get the same result as in the image you sent. I gave you the tools that can help you get the exact result. You must learn to use it and get the exact match.